# Dynamically changing columnVisibility in MUI DataGrid (x-data-grid v6.0.4)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How does one dynamically change the `columnVisibilityModel` in MUI x-data-grid v6?

I'm currently doing a:

```
    const [columnVisibilityModel, setColumnVisibilityModel] = useState<GridColumnVisibilityModel>({
        id: false,
        order: false,
        stage: viewMode !== "question"
    });
```

And then a:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if(viewMode === "question") {
            setColumnVisibilityModel({
                ...columnVisibilityModel,
                stage: false
        })
        } else {
            setColumnVisibilityModel({
                ...columnVisibilityModel,
                stage: true
        })
        }
    }, [viewMode])
```

When I console.log the `columnVisibilityModel`, I see it doing what I'd expect when I click the button that toggles `viewMode` (another state thing).

The rows (and order) of the data grid changes to reflect the different 'mode' of viewing the data. What **doesn't** happen is that the `stage` column appears and disappears. It's initialized as not visible, and it just stays that way.

The `DataGrid` (with styling) looks like:

```
   <StyledDataGrid
      rows={chartData}
      columns={columns}
      getRowId={(row) => row.id + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}
      initialState={{ 
          pagination: {paginationModel: {pageSize: 100}},
          columns: {
              columnVisibilityModel
          }
       }}
   />
```

My understanding from https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-visibility/#controlled-visible-columns is that when I change that object, the grid should change.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use use the `apiRef` to update the `columnVisibilityModel` and take control of the visibility of the columns.

1. Import `useGridApiRef` from `@mui/x-data-grid`.
2. Create a reference using `useGridApiRef`.
3. Pass the `apiRef` to the `DataGrid`.
4. Use the `apiRef` to update the column visibility inside the `useEffect`.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { DataGrid, GridApiRef, useGridApiRef } from '@mui/x-data-grid';

// Your other imports and code

export default function App() {
  const [columnVisibilityModel, setColumnVisibilityModel] = useState<GridColumnVisibilityModel>({
    id: false,
    order: false,
    stage: viewMode !== 'question',
  });

  const apiRef = useGridApiRef(); // Create the apiRef

  useEffect(() => {
    if (viewMode === 'question') {
      setColumnVisibilityModel({
        ...columnVisibilityModel,
        stage: false,
      });
    } else {
      setColumnVisibilityModel({
        ...columnVisibilityModel,
        stage: true,
      });
    }

    // Update the column visibility using apiRef
    apiRef.current.setColumnVisibility('stage', viewMode !== 'question');
  }, [viewMode, apiRef, columnVisibilityModel]);

  return (
    <StyledDataGrid
      apiRef={apiRef} // Pass the apiRef to the DataGrid
      rows={chartData}
      columns={columns}
      getRowId={(row) => row.id + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}
      initialState={{
        pagination: { paginationModel: { pageSize: 100 } },
        columns: {
          columnVisibilityModel,
        },
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: That was the ticket! Thanks!